# How to delete files automatically after one month?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using `S3` as a storage for my files and I have some files I need to delete them after like one month!

I know I have to use `laravel scheduler` but these files  that I need to delete is not store in database to just delete them!

So is there any to delete the files in the bucket based on the date of create this file ?!

Comment: I would start here: [Amazon scheduled tasks (cron)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html)

Comment: You can have a look to object expiration feature on S3 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [Object lifecycle management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) on the Amazon S3 bucket.

This includes the ability to 'expire' (delete) objects after a given period of time.

Comment: Thank so much for this, I just create a new  lifecycle rule and here is my config, please correct me if I get it wrong! First: https://ibb.co/CWhNcnK. second: https://ibb.co/B2t8p9G

Comment: Your configuration is set to "Permanently delete _previous_ versions of objects". This is only applicable to buckets that have Versioning activated. If you simply wish to delete the file, then select "Expire _current_ versions of objects".